# Record with Focusrite Scarlett 6i6 and non-asio applications

Tags: recording, audio

Edit: in short, I would like to record both the images from my webcam and the audio from my Focusrite Scarlett external sound card in a (any) single recording application. Such applications generally don't handle Asio and I receive no sound in the "Line In" input of the WDM driver.

My goal is to record a few music improvisations with my webcam, my keyboard and my external sound card.
My keyboard is connected to the audio inputs of my sound card (Focusrite Scarlett 6i6), which is itself connected to my computer via USB.
I have no problem recording sound with Asio-capable applications such as Studio One, where I can see the individual inputs of my sound card.

However, I'd like to use another application to quickly record both the webcam and audio at the same time, and it doesn't have any Asio capability.
The problem is that no sound is going through the "Line In" input that I see in Windows, even if it is defined as default recording device.

How can I have the sound go through the "Scarlette 6i6 Line In" input and be picked by all Windows applications?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to record both the line in and the webcam's mic together, or just line in + picture?

Comment: I want to record the Line In (Windows WDM driver) + the pictures

Comment: Ah, OK - then muffin's answer rather than mine - I thought you wanted to mix from 2 separate sound sources/inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I use my Scarlett Saffire 6 USB, which is a bit older, but I assume the functionality is the same...
I had the same issue with the input not being recognized by my computer.

Unfortunately, sound-cards on computers are quite useless when it comes to audio-recording. I could fix the problem by handling both, the input of my Scarlett and the output of my PC over the Scarlett itself, so the sound-card is not used at all.

To make this possible, follow these steps:

- Be sure to have all USB-drivers for your Scarlett installed
- Right-click the sound icon on your task bar
- Choose "recording devices" and set it to Line-In
- Choose "playback devices" and set it to Line-Out
- Be sure to have your output-device (speakers, headphones...) plugged into your Scarlett
- Disable other recording/playback devices if needed

Now that the whole sound is being managed by your audio-interface, it should be possible to record everything at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, but how would that help me record both the images from my webcam and the audio from my Scarlett in a single Windows Application (knowing that most of them don't support Asio). The webcam recording applications I've tried can't see the individual inputs from my Scarlett, and no sound is going through the Windows WDM driver "Line In".

Comment: Well the magic trick is that such an application usually uses your sound-card, but if that sound card is completely ignored, it should use your defined input and output, because there is no individual input and output anymore (since all sounds go over the same device)

Answer (score 0):

*(this is not a 'platform wars' opening gambit* ;)
Windows is not very good at routing audio natively, without something like ASIO guiding it.

Received wisdom is that Plogue's [Bidule](http://www.plogue.com/products/bidule/) (multi-platform but not cheap, $95) is the best way to route internally for audio, midi etc, without ASIO; though I haven't personally tried it yet - my Mac can already do that natively,  but it's already on my watch-list for if I need to go outside my current capabilities.